# accessibility - focus lock breaks by arrow keys when using JAWS

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, arrow-keys

I have a function that locks the focus inside a dialog.

```
<div role="dialog" aria-label="test dialog">
    <input type="text" id="a"/><br />
    <input type="text" id="b"/><br />
    <input type="text" id="c"/><br />
    <input type="text" id="d"/><br />
    <button id="buttonA">a</button>
    <button id="buttonB">b</button>
    <button id="buttonC">c</button>
</div>
```

When using Tab / Shift tab it works fine, but now I've started testing my code with JAWS, and I see that the arrow keys behave differently.

The lock dialog is something similar to the logic in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zw6w5gx2/

I tried adding the keycodes of the arrows to the 'if' statement, but than I noticed that the event isn't fired for these keys.

My dialog has role=dialog, and when using NVDA it was enough to make the arrow keys go back to their normal behavior, but it doesn't work with JAWS.

I did see that when using role=application everything is fine, but I don't want to use this role as it is not what I need here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but what you're doing here is bad practice and overcoding at the same time.
First of all, recent versions of JAWS have a built-in feature to restrict virtual cursor by a current dialog, so no need to re-implement this functionality.
Second, you should not restrict your user in any way. If you lock the focus programmatically, for a screen reader user this is analogous to an imaginary procedure where upon an action you would suddenly make all of your monitor dark, except of your dialog. This is not acceptable, that's why JAWS doesn't give you this ability.
third, in order to achieve your effect with "press Tab — get to a concrete input", you have only to indicate the proper `tabindex` attribute, then all of your Tab/Shift+Tab movements will be as expected.
The thing is that JAWS on a web page operates with a thing known as the virtual cursor. It allows a blind user to navigate through the page by using quick keys, namely letters (`h` navigates by heading, `b` by button, and so on, and so forth). That's why you see such weird (at the first glance( behavior.
However, if you absolutely need to do all these things you currently do (and you have the right to do this, inspite of what I've said before), `role="application"` is your best friend: thus the user would definitely know that his/her keys would not operate as he/she expects, and this is normal because the developer made it so.

Answer (score 1):

Jaws behaves differently when using "**virtual cursor**" mode and "**application**" mode try switching between modes using "insert + z" when in application mode the focus is moving to the tab-able elements while when in "virtual cursor" jaws is using the DOM structure to focus the next/previous elements. The same is happening with other accessibility tools like Narrator when using "scan" mode "caps lock + space" to enable/disable.